# Visio 2016 diagrams corrupt

Tags: visio

A number of my Visio 2016 diagrams appear corrupt after a recent Windows 10 and/or Office update.  It seems to particularly affect the Azure icons.  Any suggestions?

Here's a snippet from one of my corrupt diagrams:

[image]

This is how the diagram should look:

[image]

I can edit the text with no issues.  The word before "Data Warehouse" has been scrubbed my me in both images as it's a product name.

Comment: What should the word be before "Data"? Does zooming in/out affect it? Can you click on the text and edit it?

Comment: Use of the word "corrupt" is wrong. A better description of what is wrong with the diagram would have been a good idea. on the original diagram the only thing that appeared to be wrong was the poor display of the word before "Data".

Comment: Is this the standalone version of Visio 2016 or an Online version?

Comment: It's the standalone version.

Comment: I suspect this is a theme issue. Try to remove all themes from from your from your drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the checkbox "*Disable hardware graphics acceleration*" in the **Options > Advanced** menu fixed this for me:

[image: Visio options]